# Implement IEnumerable jagged array which returns transposed item

Tags: c#, linq, matrix, transpose, ienumerator

I've tried doing this myself, and it's a wowzer of a headache...

I want to be able to use LINQ to `Select` from `T[key1][key2]`, where it actually 'sees' `T[key2][key1]` (that is, a transposed matrix). The reason I'd like to do this is so I'm not having to manually transpose the array items (which is slow), but rather serve the array items transposed on-the-fly.

Unsure if this is even possible!

Edit: to add an example of this functioning:

`T[][]` or `T[,]` `.Select(item => item)`, where `item` is of type `T[]` as a collection of the Nth enumerator position.

```
int[,] matrix = new int[2,2] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
matrix = matrix.Select(item => item); //Where .Select magically transposes
//Matrix is now {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: LINQ doesn't work that way. It doesn't understand the concept of jagged arrays. I'd create a `Matrix` type with a `Transpose()` method that returns a new `Matrix` object with transposed values. Also, when you say "which is slow", I'm not sure what you mean. You mean slow to implement or slow to execute?

Comment: So, at the moment, I'm using some code to first transpose the whole array in-place, then using LINQ upon this collection. Transposition is useful for me as I want to average values across key2's, rather than key1's. What I'm trying to accomplish is an enumerator for LINQ which enumerates the keys 'swapped'.

Answer (score 1):

To write the code to traverse an array in a transposed order you just write the code to traverse the array normally; what the array's implementation of `IEnumerable` uses, but instead of traversing the lowest dimension in the outer loop and the higher dimension in the inner loop, you just reverse them:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TraverseTransposed<T>(this T[,] array)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            yield return array[i, j];
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how to use this in my case. For example, I have `T[,]` I would like to `.Select(item => item)` from, where `item` is of type `T[]` as a collection of the Nth enumerator position.

Comment: Then it sounds like you'd rather have jagged arrays, rather than a 2d array.

Comment: Yes, that is in the title, though regardless `item` would be `T[]`

Comment: @Patrick You specifically showed your code as being a 2D array, not a jagged array.  But regardless, if you want to return whole arrays, rather than just sequences, it defeats the purpose of not just transposing the whole thing.  The whole idea of having an iterator, rather than just transposing the whole thing up front, is to avoid copying all of the data over to another structure, which you can't do if you require an array, rather than an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I'm quite certain `T[][]` is jagged, `T[,]` multidimensional...
The reason I want an iterator rather than manually transposing is to avoid just that - I can 'select' with for loops easily, by using `T[key2][key1]`, and I want to provide LINQ the iterator to do this. Please see the example I've edited into the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean (is it slow?):

```
var items = new int[,] {
   {1,2,3,4,5,6},
   {10,20,30,40,50,60},
   {100,200,300,400,500,600},
};  

var transposed = new int[items.GetLength(1), items.GetLength(0)];

for (int row = 0; row < items.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < items.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
       transposed[col,row]  = items[row,col];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to copy the entire array into a new array just to traverse it in a different order.  That requires O(n) memory, rather than O(1) memory.